# NSLayoutConstraint label is in middle of image

Tags: objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

I'm attaching a UIImageView and UILabel to a UIScrollView.  I'm shrinking the image to half it's height, and when I do that, the label ends up right in the middle of the image vertically rather than right below it.  If I don't force the image smaller, the label sits right below the image as expected.

How do I shrink an image and still have my label sit right below it?

```
UIScrollView *scrollView;
UIImageView *myImage;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary;
UILabel *myLabel;

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

[myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"vacation-house-004.jpg"]];
[myImage setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[myLabel setText: @"test label"];

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

[scrollView addSubview:myImage];
[scrollView addSubview:myLabel];

scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
myImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// Set the constraints for the scroll view and the image view.
viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView, myImage, myLabel);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[myImage(==scrollView)]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[myImage(50)]-[myLabel]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, had to add: myImage.clipsToBounds = YES;

```
UIView *superView = self.view;
UIScrollView *scrollView;
UIImageView *myImage;
NSDictionary *viewsDictionary;
UILabel *myLabel;

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

myImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"vacation-house-004.jpg"];
myImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
myImage.clipsToBounds = YES;

myLabel.text = @"test label";
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[superView addSubview:scrollView];

[scrollView addSubview:myImage];
[scrollView addSubview:myLabel];

scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
myImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// Set the constraints for the scroll view and the image view.
viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(superView, scrollView, myImage, myLabel);
[superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[myImage(==scrollView)]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[myImage(150)]-[myLabel]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```